# CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Tags: c#, xslt

I am trying to write a new XSLT package. The code that I am using is

```
public virtual string CustomShowInventoryTable(String sProductID, String sVariantID)
{
        StringBuilder results = new StringBuilder("");
        if (AppLogic.AppConfigBool("ShowInventoryTable"))
        {
            results.Append(AppLogic.GetInventoryTable(ProductID, VariantID, true,     ThisCustomer.SkinID, true, false));
        }
        return results.ToString();
}
```

The error I am getting is

**Compiler Error Message:**

```
CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
```

I have tried checking the ( and ) within the file but I still get this compiled error.

Comment: The compiler should tell you which line, and which column of that line, it's complaining about. Which line is that? (And in this case what's happening before that, since this message usually means your `{}` braces are not matched properly.)

Comment: Its this linepublic virtual string CustomShowInventoryTable(String sProductID, String sVariantID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you have a couple of typos in your code:

- It should be `public virtual String`, not `string`. Or maybe `string sProductID, string sVariantID` instead of `String`, depending on which language you're working with.
- `AppLogic.GetInventoryTable(ProductID, VariantID` - are those variables defined? The ones that your method receive have different names, `sProductID` and `sVariantID`...